# Redshift Composite Sortkey - how many columns should we use?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm building several very large data tables on Amazon Redshift, that should hold data covering several frequently-queried properties with the relevant metrics.

We're using an even distribution style ("diststyle even") to have all the nodes participate in query calculations, but I am not certain about the length of the sortkey.

It definitely should be compound - every query will use first filter on date and network - but after that level I have about 7 additional relevant factors that can be queried on.
All the examples I've seen use a compound sort key of 2-3 fields, 4 at most.

My question is -why not use a sortkey that includes all the key fields in the table? What are the downsides for having a long sortkey?

Comment: Well, if you build an index involving all the columns in your table it will take up more space than if you build an index involving only a few of the columns.  So if space is a concern, then this might be an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

VACUUM will also take longer if you have several sort keys.